# Cron expression not correct for Hangfire Recurring Jobs

Tags: cron, hangfire

I have a few jobs configured to be executed on an ASP.NET MVC Site through Hangfire. Hangfire uses a cron expression to trigger said jobs. I thought I had the expression correct, but the triggering is happening too often. [image: Image of cron schedule]

As you can see, the top job just finished executing 6 minutes previously and its next execution is expected to happen in an hour.  But the cron expression, as I understand it, says it should only trigger once a day at 2 AM.  Even accounting for different time zones, it shouldn't be happening on an hourly basis.

Do I have the cron expression incorrect? I will admit to not being completely knowledgeable about that, though from my reading I thought I had it correct.

Thanks

Comment: Not all `cron` implementations understand the `*/1` notation.  Wouldn't `*` do just as well there?

Comment: Logically, that sounds right. I don't know enough to say for sure, but I can give it a shot.

Comment: So I just deployed it to the server again this morning with the suggested change, but the frequency is still every hour or so. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but every time I forget this, I end up back here...

Hangfire (at least the version pictured) uses NCrontab (https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) which allows CRON expressions of 5 or 6 parts. If you use 6 parts, the first part is seconds, the second part is minutes. This is why the job in the pictured example was ran at 3:02.

Most answers I have run across seem to only show the 5 part version of CRON expressions.

From the above URL:

```
* * * * * *
- - - - - -
| | | | | |
| | | | | +--- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
| | | | +----- month (1 - 12)
| | | +------- day of month (1 - 31)
| | +--------- hour (0 - 23)
| +----------- min (0 - 59)
+------------- sec (0 - 59)
```

To trigger once daily at 2am would be `0 0 2 * * ?`